# CSV File and TypeError: a bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a problem regarding to writing CSV file. Everytime I write my CSV file using python suddenly there is a blank space in every rows [Here is the CSV file with blank space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbFxv.png). So I search for the solution in the internet. Then some website says that I just need to change "w" to "wb" but after I try to run the program an error occur.

Error : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

My Code :

```
seat =[]
csvfile = open('coba.csv') 
seating = csv.reader(csvfile)
for line in seating:
    seat.append(line)

print("Buy seat ?")
answer_1 = input("Answer : ")
if (answer_1 == "yes"):
    answer_2 = input("Enter preferred seat: ")
    if (answer_2 == "A1"):
        row = 1
        column = 0
        seat[row][column] = "X"
        writer = csv.writer(open('coba.csv', 'wb'))
        writer.writerows(seat)
        for line in seat:
            print(' | '.join(line))
```

CSV File :

```
[Business]
A1,A2,A3,A4,A5
B1,B2,B3,B4,B5
[Economy]
C1,C2,C3,C4,C5
D1,D2,D3,D4,D5
```

Comment: Where does the Error occur? What line of code causes it?

Comment: writer = csv.writer(open('coba.csv', 'wb'))

Comment: Can you show the traceback, please?

Comment: Your file isn't in a valid csv format.

Comment: You get the error, because 'wb' expects binary data to be written, but the csv module attempts to write string.

Comment: The proper way to open a csv file in Python 3 is via `open(filenname, mode='r', newline='')` for reading and with `mode='w'` for writing (as shown in the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv)).

Comment: @AvivShai File "coba.py", line 163, in <module>
    writer.writerows(seat)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: if i use notepad there is no blank space in everyrow, but if I use excel there is

Answer (score 0):

You are reading in 'r' and writing in 'wb'

You either have to change the data type of each element or simply

**Change `wb` to `w` and it works**

Full code

```
import csv

seat =[]
csvfile = open('coba.csv')
seating = csv.reader(csvfile)
for line in seating:
    seat.append(line)

print("Buy seat ?")
answer_1 = input("Answer : ")
if (answer_1 == "yes"):
    answer_2 = input("Enter preferred seat: ")
    if (answer_2 == "A1"):
        row = 1
        column = 0
        seat[row][column] = "X"
        writer = csv.writer(open('coba.csv', 'w'))
        writer.writerows(seat)
        for line in seat:
            print(' | '.join(line))
```

Output

```
Buy seat ?
Answer : yes
Enter preferred seat: A1
[Business]
X | A2 | A3 | A4 | A5
B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5
[Economy]
C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5
D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | D5
```

Opening the generated file in excel

[image: in EXCEL]

Comment: yeah i know it works if i use "w", but the problem is when i use "w" there is suddenly blank space every row

Comment: Are you on windows? If so try using `newline=''`. in line `csv.writer(open('coba.csv', 'w', newline=''))`

Comment: tried already, only in excel random blank appear

Comment: You mean when opening the generated file in excel?

Comment: yeah, so if I run the program for the second time all the position of my seat is messed up because of the blankspace in excel

Comment: I added the image of excel. I do not see any additional blank lines with `newline=''`. am I missing something?

Comment: hmmm so it is my excel problem?

Comment: Not sure. What do you see in raw csv. Any additional new lines?

Comment: no any blank line between any rows, the blank line appear after file is generated

Comment: this is frustating :<

Comment: Try some alternatives for excel. Python also has library to write excel directly. try that.

Comment: is it possible if I use txt file instead of csvfile for my program?

Comment: CSV is same as TXT file. There is no difference except the rules of CSV and extension.

Comment: it is very confusing if I open the generated file using excel there is blankspace, but if open the excel file using notepad the all the blank lien appear in excel is missing..

Comment: Can you try replacing X5 instead of X1. May be there is problem in input file itself. Wild guess I might be wrong

Comment: what happen if I uninstall excel then operate the csv file using notepad?

Comment: That should be fine if that's acceptable for you

Comment: i ahve unistall my excel, then the same problem appear again, everytime i read the file and put it in a list then print the list, there is a blank space in every rows.. This is frustasting

Answer (score 0):

Use the `newline` keyword argument in your `open()` calls,

```
seat = []
with open('coba.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    seating = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in seating:
        seat.append(line)

print("Buy seat ?")
answer_1 = input("Answer : ")
if answer_1 == "yes":
    answer_2 = input("Enter preferred seat: ")
    if answer_2 == "A1":
        row = 1
        column = 0
        seat[row][column] = "X"
        with open('coba.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerows(seat)
            for line in seat:
                print(' | '.join(line))
```

Comment: try already using newline='' , there is still a blankspace every rows